# How to change gltf material to cartoon material?

Tags: three.js, shader, gltf

I'm not familiar with three.js and shader. I export a gltf dragon model with texture from C4d and load it into meshstandard material in three.js. I want to change them into cartoon material. With the model stroke, I can traverse the gltf material like this

```js
mesh.traverse((node: any) => {
    let newMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
        },
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    });

    node.material = newMat
});
```

I found a cartoon rendering tutorial https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_37683659/article/details/79953500

But I still don't know how to combine this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `ShaderMaterial` when the library already provides `MeshToonMaterial` for you. ShaderMaterial is very advanced, and requires you to write your own custom shaders. You probably want something simple like this:

```js
mesh.traverse((node: any) => {
    let newMat = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial(parameters);
    node.material = newMat
});
```

To see which parameters you can use, [visit the docs for ToonMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshToonMaterial).

Comment: Thanks, but is there any method to convert meshstandardmaterial into meshtoonmaterial? node. material is meshstandardmaterial, which contains many parameters

Comment: There's no built-in method to convert one to the other. You could extract the property form one and assign to the other, like `newMat.color = oldMat.color`, but Standard material has too many properties that Toon lacks, like roughness, metalness, envMap, etc, so there's no way to "convert" one into the other.